# Передать несколько переменных из ViewModel на другую страницу . Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Перехожу на другую страницу таким способом

```dart
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/result_page');
```

Нужно на этот result page передать 2 переменные, как это сделать при помощи Provider'a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь для этого вам необходимо указать свойство `arguments:`

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/result_page', arguments: '123')
```

Или

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/result_page', arguments: ['123', '123'])
```

А для того чтобы принять эти аргументы на новой странице используйте после `initState()` метода:

```
String s = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

Comment: спасибо большое, вы меня выручили